# Adding external packages to elastic beanstalk python app

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was wanting to use some non-standard python packages in my project and was wondering how to add them. What is the benefit of using the AWS eb config files (.ebextensions and requirements.txt) rather than just downloading and including the package in my actual project under a `lib` directory like you would with a java application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by including it in the requirements.txt, you can include only the packages you are calling.  Pip then takes care of installing the dependencies and checking the versions.

This has the additional advantage of when you are changing or upgrading your project, you can specify a new version of the library you are using and all the dependent libraries will also be updated.

Comment: Also, it will speed-up the deployment process, as you won't have to transfer the library, lighten-up your git repo, and cut a few cents from S3 fees :-)

Comment: It also lets you define different requirements for things like Production and Development. Example, I always have ipython and ipdb in development, but not in production